# How to apply function on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, lambda

I have a sample Dataframe(`df`):

```
                               Time             Price
Equity(231 [IBM])   2016-05-10 00:00:00+00:00  150.04
Equity(2574 [TSLA]) 2016-04-29 00:00:00+00:00  248.43
```

I want to apply function `findy()` on each row using values in dataframe as well as values from other variables and store those values in new column `Predicted`.

I have these variables(the values are copied from output):

```
high_1 = Equity(231 [IBM])      151.676
         Equity(2574 [TSLA])    258.310
         Equity(0 [AAPL])       111.710

idx_1 =  Equity(231 [IBM])     2016-04-18 00:00:00+00:00
         Equity(2574 [TSLA])   2016-04-18 00:00:00+00:00
         Equity(0 [AAPL])      2016-04-14 00:00:00+00:00
```

I want to apply this function:

```
def findy(s,Time,Price,idx_1, high_1, idx_last):
    idx = [idx_1.loc[s.index], Time]
    x = matplotlib.dates.date2num(idx)
    y = [high_1.loc[s.index], Price]
    coefficients = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    polynomial = np.poly1d(coefficients)
    x_axis = np.linspace(x[0], idx_last + 1, 3)  # linspace(start, end, num)
    y_axis = polynomial(x_axis)
    return Predicted_Value
```

I tried using this code:

```
df["Predicted"] = df.apply(lambda s: 
                          findy(s,s['Time'],s['Price'],idx_1,high_1,idx_last))
```

In the `lambda` function, am trying to get the `index`,`Time`, `Price` of each stock and insert into the function and use those values for the operations inside `findy()`.
But am Getting errors like, `KeyError: ('Time', 'occurred at index Time')`
The major problem is sitting inside the `lambda` and how am accessing values from rows.

If you want more clarification feel free to ask.

Comment: I think you just need to add an additional argument to your call to apply. `df["Predicted"] = df.apply(lambda s: findy(s,s['Time'],s['Price'],idx_1,high_1,idx_last), 1)` would tell it to apply row by row. Right now, it's trying to go column by column.

Comment: you mean `axis=1`? i tried but i still get errors.

Comment: Are the errors the same or different?

Comment: @JCVanHamme when i use `axis=1`, it raises `KeyError: ("None of [Index(['Time', 'Price'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]", 'occurred at index Equity(231 [IBM])')`

Comment: @ArJuN, where and how did you define `idx_1,high_1,idx_last`?

Comment: @MaxU those variables i derived from another dataframe, but i assure u, problem isnt in those variables, problem is in syntax of `lambda/apply` more specifically in `s['Time']` and similar.

Comment: @ArJuN, i do believe you. But most of the times we want to reproduce your issue/error/problem/behavior in order to be able to help you... ;-)

Comment: i can give you full code, but it uses library `zipline` which has tonnes of dependencies. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `findy` function. The first line tries to do `idx_1.loc[s.index]`. The value of `s.index` is something like `Index(['Time', 'Price'], dtype='object')`. It's then looking for ['Time', 'Price'] in the index of `idx_1`, which doesn't exist.

I think you have to reevaluate your `findy` function. Even if that first line worked, you turn around and pass that result to `matplotlib.dates.date2num`, which is expecting a `datetime` or sequence of `datetimes`. That's not going to be what `idx` contains.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but `'Time','Price'` are column names, index is the `Equity(231 [IBM])`, can you please look more into it, i really appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, 'Time' and 'Price' are column names for the dataframe, but when you pass in the series object that represents a row of that frame, they become the index values. You should double check what `s.index` looks like in your `findy` function.

Comment: hmm, makes sense, i'll find it out. Thanks :)